# Android - Create google map projections V2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, map-projections

I embedded a PNG image on the map (version 1) using Overlays:

```
    ....
    Bitmap map_scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(map_png, map_png.getWidth(), map_png.getHeight(), true);

....

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, false);
        if(shadow) return;
        Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();

        Point leftTop = new Point();
        Point rightTop = new Point();
        Point rightBottom = new Point();
        Point leftBottom = new Point();

        projection.toPixels(topGeoPoint, leftTop);
        projection.toPixels(new GeoPoint(topGeoPoint.getLatitudeE6(), bottomGeoPoint.getLongitudeE6()), rightTop);
        projection.toPixels(bottomGeoPoint, rightBottom);
        projection.toPixels(new GeoPoint(bottomGeoPoint.getLatitudeE6(), topGeoPoint.getLongitudeE6()), leftBottom);

        if (
                (leftTop.x < 0 || leftTop.y < 0) && 
                (rightTop.x < 0 || rightTop.y < 0) && 
                (rightBottom.x < 0 || rightBottom.y < 0) && 
                (leftBottom.x < 0 || leftBottom.y < 0)) {
            // Not on screen? Don't draw the overlay
            return;
        }

        //      GeoPoint mapCenter = mapView.getMapCenter();
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        canvas.drawBitmap(original, null, new Rect(leftTop.x, leftTop.y, rightBottom.x, rightBottom.y), paint);


}
```

I would like to migrate the code to version 2. Do you have any advices? Is there any similar components for do that in Google Map v2?

Best regards

---

The screenshot. [image]

Comment: Hi Macie, I uploaded the screenshot. As you can see I would like to put over the map a PNG image, but fixed by the top-left (latitude-longitude) corner  and by the bottom-right (latitude-longitude) corner. If I zoom in or zoom out the map, the PNG image should be resized

Comment: That's very easy with GroundOverlay in API v2.

Comment: Great Macie, that´s the solution and veryyy easy

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I miss understood, but if you want to add markers to your map, you simple can do it like this:

```
 private MarkerOptions createMapMarker(LocationWO mLocation) {

    MarkerOptions mMarker = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(
                    new LatLng(mLocation.getmLatitude(), mLocation
                            .getmLongitude()))
            .title(mLocation.getmName())
            .snippet(mLocation.getmName())
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.map_pin_debug));
    return mMarker;
}
```

Check the official doku https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker There are examples for drawing shapes at the map as well, if I didn't get your question right: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes